# Deleting subdocuments using mongoose returning error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete all the sub-documents of my collection.

**mongoose schema :**

```
//productSchema
var pdtSchema = new Schema({
    "productId" : {type : String},
    "product" : {type : String},
    "item no" : {type : String},
});
    
var shopSchema = new Schema({
    "providerId" : {type : String},
    "provider" : {type : String},
    "products" : [pdtSchema]
}, { collection:"shopdetails" });
    
module.exports.Shops    = mongoose.model('Shops',shopSchema);
module.exports.Products = mongoose.model('Products',pdtSchema);
```

I have stored a bulk of data inside the collection and I need to delete all the products(that is the whole `pdtSchema` data).

**code:**

```
router.post('/delete',function (req,res) {
   var providerId = req.body.providerId;
   model.Shops.findById({"providerId" : providerId},function(err, doc) {     
     console.log(doc.products) // returns whole products here...
     doc.products.remove();
     doc.save(function(err,data){
       res.json({"msg":"deleted"});
    });
   });
 });
```

**error:**

```
(node:16351) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "[Function]" at path "_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`$unset`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator which deletes the `products` field with the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** method. Using the traditional approach of first
retrieving the document with **[`findById()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)** only works with a valid `ObjectId`, in your case you are only providing a non-`ObjectId` string, hence the error.

```
router.post('/delete',function (req,res) {
    var providerId = req.body.providerId;
    model.Shops.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "providerId": providerId },
        { "$unset": { "products": "" } },
        { "new": true }
        function(err, doc) {     
            console.log(doc) // returns modified doc here...
            res.json({"msg": "Field deleted"});
        }
    );
 });
```

---

If you want to keep the array field but remove all its elements, use **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** as

```
router.post('/delete',function (req,res) {
    var providerId = req.body.providerId;
    model.Shops.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "providerId": providerId },
        { "$set": { "products": [] } },
        { "new": true }
        function(err, doc) {     
            console.log(doc) // returns doc with empty products here...
            res.json({"msg": "Products deleted"});
        }
    );
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are saving "providerId" in shopSchema as type String, even though it is a mongoose object.
So, comparing a string type against a mognoose ObjectId type gives a cast error.

Instead do this,

```
var shopSchema = new Schema({
    "providerId" : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId
        ref : schema which they are a reference to},
        "provider" : {type : String},
        "products" : [pdtSchema]
    }, { collection:"shopdetails" });
```

But, I think if `providerId` refers to a shop Id, then it should be `_id` only.

`model.findById()` works with `_id`

Comment: It is giving an error because you are using model.findById() function, which works with _id, but you are trying it with providerId which us of type String